# How to set the callerID in Plivo android sdk?

Tags: android, plivo, caller-id

I want to set also the caller id when I make a call not only the destination number and I can't find anything in the documentation about it for Android SDK.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To set the callerID in Plivo Android SDK, we must use the SIP Headers. Have a look at the instructions that I got from Plivo support team:

"
We can send custom SIP header in the Android SDK by following the below steps,
1. Load the example application in Android studio. [Link:](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-android-sdk2-examples) 
2. Now Navigate to Voice activity section under "com.plivo.voicecalling". Permalink of the referenced line: [permalink](https://github.com/plivo/plivo-android-sdk2-examples/blob/3a1f8aa674dfc8a87661f220407dcdcfd4ebe8bc/app/src/main/java/com/plivo/voicecalling/Activities/VoiceActivity.java#L409) 
Add the below code in the "onOutgoingCall" method. 
public void onOutgoingCall(Outgoing outgoing) {

Map extraHeaders = new HashMap<>();

extraHeaders.put("X-PH-Header1", "12345");
extraHeaders.put("X-PH-Header2", "34567");

outgoing.callH(phoneNumberText.getText().toString(),extraHeaders);

}

Also, do not forget to import java.util.HashMap , java.util.Map while importing other packages.

4. Now build the example application and try sending invite where you can see the extra headers sent.

Request-Line: INVITE sip:XYXYXYXYXYXY@production-mediaserver:5060 SIP/2.0
Message Header
    Record-Route: 
    Record-Route: 
    Via: SIP/2.0/TCP Media server IP:5060;branch=z9hG4bKfab6.a38be8f72872a8c2cd9e747289f2212d.0;i=cef422
    Via: SIP/2.0/TLS IP:38242;received=IP;rport=38242;branch=z9hG4bKPj1e4bc7fc-3fa9-4439-a2e0-dacd6696b118;alias
    Max-Forwards: 69
    From: sip:xyxyxyxyxyx@phone.plivo.com;tag=73b5b6fe-c1a7-4744-b3b1-a68409840c83
    To: sip:xnxnxnxnx@phone.plivo.com
    Contact: 
    Call-ID: d50f1995-82ad-4bdc-8a3d-3f13bc2edf1d
    CSeq: 14979 INVITE
    Route: 
    Supported: replaces, 100rel, timer, norefersub
    Session-Expires: 1800
    Min-SE: 90
    User-Agent: PlivoAndroidSDK-v2.0
    X-PH-Header2: 34567
    X-PH-Header1: 12345
    Content-Type: application/sdp
    Content-Length:   351
    P-hint: inbound
    X-PlivoSIPDestination: sip:XXXXXXXXXXX@phone.plivo.com
    X-PlivoFromSIPUser: sip:dXYXYXYXYXYX@phone.plivo.com
    X-PlivoInboundGateway: phone.plivo.com
    X-PlivoMediaServer: sip:XXXXXXXXXXX@production-mediaserver:5060

Note: The special characters allowed in the SIP extra headers are +-_()
"X-PH" is a must in Extra Header keys, otherwise it will be ignored at the server side.
"